# Powershell script for user profile properties in SharePoint Online 2013?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Does anyone know of a Powershell script that can be used to pull user profile information from SharePoint Online 2013?  The SharePoint server scripts are useless.

Particularly, we are looking for a script that will tell us if a user has a MySite/SkyDrive/OneDrive personal site

Answer (score 1):

The following [script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2014/02/27/office365-retrieve-user-profiles-using-csom.aspx) allows you to access user profile properties for Sharepoint Online users.
 Under PersonalSpace you can find either a link or an empty field. It will let you know if the user has the personal site.

```
Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Identify users in the Site Collection
$Users = $Context.Web.SiteUsers
$Context.Load($Users)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Create People Manager object to retrieve profile data
$PeopleManager = New-Object   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)
Foreach ($User in $Users)
{
$UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($User.LoginName)
$Context.Load($UserProfile)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
If ($UserProfile.Email -ne $null)
    {
    Write-Host "User:" $User.LoginName -ForegroundColor Green
    $UserProfile.UserProfileProperties
    Write-Host ""
    }  
}
```

**EDIT**
Actually there is another way, much simpler, that doesn't involve scripting and still shows you which users have personal site.

Connect via SharePoint Management Shell and write in the console:
Get-SPOUser -Site https://domain-my.sharepoint.com

You will get a list of list of users (+some extras) who created their personal site.

Comment: Is there a way to get this information using the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a script that does this right now. [Check out this example script](https://github.com/brendankarl/Office-365-PowerShell/blob/master/Analysis/OD4B-SharedWithEveryoneUsage.ps1), which uses the user profile service proxy to iterate through users. The script checks if($Url). If this value is true, the user has a provisioned OneDrive site.

Comment: Please post the relevant code directly in your answer, not by linking to an external site.